# Tiny, round black bug found in bed twice

Tags: bugs, bug-identification

I found a black bug like this on two separate occassions on my bed, both times about morning to midday. I live in Vaughan, Ontario, Canada though not near any major wooded areas.

The first time I saw it was during the summer and second time was today during the winter. They don't move fast, are a little less than 0.5 cm long with shiny, hard shells. I don't usually wake up feeling itchy but today when I found the bug again, I noticed a little itchy bump on my knee (which was covered by my clothes) that looks like a small, mild mosquito bite but it could be unrelated.

I don't have any pets if it matters. I've checked around and under my bed + bedframe before but couldn't find anything. Any help is appreciated.

The first 5 images are from the summer and the last from winter.

[image: s1]
[image: s2]
[image: s3]
[image: s4]
[image: s5]
[image: w1]
[image: w2]

Comment: Looks like a well fed tick to me

Comment: If it is a tick, it should explode into a bloody mess when crushed.

Comment: What is this, I have them too. Hard shell not a tick.. bites at night and leaves an itchy pimple like bite. I don't know when it's biting .. I am in central Florida near the ocean and river. We've never seen these in over 20 years can't find them by searching